# What type of switch do I need to plug into a gosund outlet to open and close a garage door?

Tags: switch, doors, garage, wifi, smart-switch

I have a Gosund switch that plugs into an outlet. I’d like to plug it into the outlet near my garage door opener and open and close the garage door. What type of switch can I plug into the gosund outlet to then wire to the garage door opener. It’s just a simple momentary switch to open or close the garage door. My security camera will let me see if the garage door is open or closed so I don’t need any logic in the switch. I think I just need a momentary switch that will throw when the outlet changes state. Any ideas if such a switch is available?[image]

Comment: So this smart switch has a momentary feature where it will turn on and off?  What you're looking for is a "relay".

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the [wi-fi enabled garage door opener switch](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075H7Z5L8?tag=thewire06-20&linkCode=xm2&ascsubtag=AwEAAAAAAAAAAJA1)?

Comment: A simple relay on/off probably doesn’t work.  The garage door control is typically momentary contact.  There is such an animal as a momentary relay which you would likely (I didn’t research) need 2, one for plug turning off and one for on.  There may be a programmable momentary relay that would work either way.   But what does ON mean?  You don’t know if the door has been opened or closed by another control.  I second the comment above, but will add there are more smart garage door controls than one, myQ is however a very good system.

Comment: @Isherwood that wins twice, first it is a "ships from and sold by Amazon" product, so you're more likely to get a product actually listed by UL/NRTL, and it is also low-voltage so it wouldn't matter anyway.   Sonoff is unlisted unsafe trash that can only be sold on ebay,  Ali or Amz Marketplace.

Comment: @Tyson, that's why I asked if the outlet had a momentary function.  I wasn't clear if he had the momentary part figured out and just needed a relay or if he needed more than that.

Comment: The outlet that the garage door is plugged into does not make the garage door go up and down as it simply provides power,  unplugging it and plugging it back in does not make the garage door go back up so controlling the power of the outlet therefore will not make the garage door go up, it will still have to have a remote control or a button that tells it when  to go up or down

Comment: It is not my intent to control the garage door opener by cycling the power. I just want a switch that I can plug into the gosund and then connect the low voltage control wires to it. So, I’m looking for a momentary switch to plug into the gosund and wire to the opener control.

Answer (score 3):

The garage door needs **[safety switches](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Chamberlain-Garage-Door-Opener-Replacement-Safety-Sensors-2-Pack-801CB/100651226)**, as well as a reversing switch, a switch to detect end of travel ([limit switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_switch)) and a switch to detect that correct force has  been applied to keep the door closed. Simply turning the power to the whole door-opener on and off does nothing.

If you want to use the Gosund outlet to bypass the **remote control** terminals, you'd need to rewire the inside of the Gosund switch, or use an external 120 VAC relay to provide only **momentary** switched contacts **without 120 VAC applied across them**. From your question, this appears to beyond your current capabilities, and could lead to shocking results.

Comment: Don’t need to sense anything. Just need a momentary switch that can itself be toggled by the gosund.

Comment: The switch would have to make a momentary contact when Gosund closes, *and also again when it opens*, or you'd need to press the control twice to get one action. It would also need to be *isolated* between the 120 VAC Gosund and the low-voltage (probably 12-24 VAC) nergized realy contacts on the door opener. Perhaps someone in the Electrical Engineering StackExchange could help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/